# Why button have to be pressed extra one time to be disabled in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, button, conditional-statements

this is my first question in stackoverflow. I am making my very first page, where I apply Javascript. I have a little score keeper. Every player has their own score counting and button. Before beginning you can select what you want to play up to. My problem is when counting is over (one player won) buttons has to be disabled, but they disable only after extra one click on them. I don`t understand why. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="main-info">
            <div class="text">
                <h1> <span id="firstScore">0</span> to <span id="secondScore">0</span></h1>  
            </div>
            <div class="choose">
                <label for="choose-score">Playing to</label>
<select name="score" id="score">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
            </div>
            <button class="buttonOne" role="button"">+1 Player One</button>
            <button class="buttonTwo">+1 Player Two</button>
            <button class="reset">Reset</button>

        </div>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
const firstPlayer = document.querySelector(".buttonOne");
const firstScore = document.querySelector("#firstScore");
const secondButton = document.querySelector(".buttonTwo");
const chooseScore = document.querySelector("#score");
const secondScore = document.querySelector("#secondScore");

let scoreOne = 0;
firstPlayer.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (scoreOne < chooseScore.value) {
    scoreOne = scoreOne + 1;
  } else {
    firstPlayer.disabled = true;
    secondButton.disabled = true;
  }
  firstScore.innerText = `${scoreOne}`;
  console.log(`this is score of First Player ${scoreOne}`);
});

let scoreTwo = 0;
secondButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (scoreTwo < chooseScore.value) {
    scoreTwo = scoreTwo + 1;
  } else {
    firstPlayer.disabled = true;
    secondButton.disabled = true;
  }
  secondScore.innerText = `${scoreTwo}`;
});
```

I tried to write conditions in another ways: without else, make new one, tried switch, starting count from 1 or -1, and in condition written

```
if (scoreTwo < chooseScore.value - 1)
```

or  chooseScore.value +1
But it doesn`t work. This is my first try and I hope you will help me with my issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this, you should only check the condition when you have to disable the `buttons`.

```js
const firstPlayer = document.querySelector(".buttonOne");
const firstScore = document.querySelector("#firstScore");
const secondButton = document.querySelector(".buttonTwo");
const chooseScore = document.querySelector("#score");
const secondScore = document.querySelector("#secondScore");

let scoreOne = 0;
firstScore.innerText =0;
secondScore.innerText=0;
console.log("-> ",parseInt(chooseScore.value ,10))
firstPlayer.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  scoreOne+=1;  
  firstScore.innerText = `${scoreOne}`;
  if (firstScore.innerText ===chooseScore.value ) { 
    firstPlayer.disabled = true;
    secondButton.disabled = true;
  } 
});

let scoreTwo = 0; 
secondButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    scoreTwo = scoreTwo + 1;  
    secondScore.innerText = `${scoreTwo}`;

    if(secondScore.innerText === chooseScore.value){
      firstPlayer.disabled = true;
      secondButton.disabled = true;
  } 
});
```

```html
<div class="main-info">
            <div class="text">
                <h1> <span id="firstScore">0</span> to <span id="secondScore">0</span></h1>  
            </div>
            <div class="choose">
                <label for="choose-score">Playing to</label>
<select name="score" id="score">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
            </div>
            <button class="buttonOne" role="button"">+1 Player One</button>
            <button class="buttonTwo">+1 Player Two</button>
            <button class="reset">Reset</button>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an edge-case logic error.

```js
  if (scoreOne < chooseScore.value) {
    scoreOne = scoreOne + 1;
  } else {
    firstPlayer.disabled = true;
    secondButton.disabled = true;
  }
```

`else` is not appropriate here because there is a case where both blocks of code need to execute. When the score is 4, the `if` block executes and increments the score to 5, but doesn't disable the buttons immediately because that code is in the `else` block.

The logic should probably go like this, with two unrelated `if` blocks:

```js
  if (scoreOne < chooseScore.value) {
    scoreOne = scoreOne + 1;
  }
  if (scoreOne >= chooseScore.value) {
    firstPlayer.disabled = true;
    secondButton.disabled = true;
  }
```

Comment: thank you for explanation, your suggestion is working.  When I tried by myself I messed up with logic. You helped me a lot)